# Rotating an image in Python

Tags: python, image, rotate

So I am making an "Asteroids" like game and I can principally get my sprites image to rotate but when I do, the image gets kinda torn apart. This is the method I am using for rotation. Any help would be appreciated.

> def turnLeft(self):
>
> ```
>    rotatedSurf1 = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image,10)
>    rotatedRect1 = rotatedSurf1.get_rect()
>    rotatedRect1.center = (25,25)
>    self.image.blit(rotatedSurf1,rotatedRect1)
> ```

Comment: Please define "torn apart", if possible via a screenshot with a before and after part.

Comment: The image kinda like swirls into a mess of pixels, like it is being blended, it gets worse as you rotate more and more.  It might be good to mention also the the image rotates as the player keeps the left arrow key down.

Comment: You want to change this line `self.image.blit(rotatedSurf1,rotatedRect1)` to something like `self.backgroundSurface.blit(rotatedSurf1,rotatedRect1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with pygame, but likely it does not like the image being repeatedly rotated and blitted onto itself.

Check out if [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19316827/3005167) works for you.

**Explanation**

Rotating an image is inaccurate. Unless you rotate exactly by multiples of 90 degrees, you never get an exact pixel-to-pixel mapping. In other words, you loose a small amount of information when you rotate. Since you replace the original image with the rotated version, this information is lost forever. Thus, the effect gets worse the more you rotate.

You should *never* modify the original image. Instead, store the rotation angle in a variable, increase/decrease this angle when pressing left/right, and rotate by that angle.
Then, you can store the rotate image (`rotatedSurf1`, `rotatedRect1`) as a member variable and blit it to the screen when drawing the scene. Do *not* blit the rotated image back onto the original!

```
def turnLeft(self):
    self.angle += 10
    self.rotatedSurf = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self. angle)
    self.rotatedRect = self.self.rotatedSurf.get_rect()
    self.rotatedRect.center = (25, 25)
```

Don't forget to initalize self.angle to 0.
In the drawing function instead of doing something like `display.blit(self.image)`, now do `display.blit(self.rotatedSurf, rotatedRect)`.

Comment: I am using this method by storing the surface of the sprite in rotatedSurft1.

Comment: Doesn't `image.blit` draw the source (`rotatedSurf1` in your case) into `image`?